# Programmatically select and deselect text in Mobile Safari

Tags: ios, cordova, web, mobile-safari

In mobile web pages of mobile browsers, user can long tap and select text. Tapping outside clears the selection.
I want to do this programatically.
In Android this works,

```
window.getSelection().addRange(range)

window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
```

And this works too.

```
document.execCommand("Unselect");
```

Problem is nothing works in iOS (Mobile Safari).

Help is greatly appreciated to get this working in iOS.

Thank you.